# Installing package from different sources gives different performance

Tags: r, devtools, rcpparmadillo

I have tried installing the *RcppArmadillo* package *sparta* (which is on CRAN) using three different methods.

1. `install.packages("sparta")`
2. `devtools::install()` (inside the package folder)
3. `devtools::build()` and then `install.package("path_to_build_file, repos = NULL, type = "source")`

I then benchmarked a specific function, *marg*, from the *sparta* package and it turned out that installing with 1) and 3) yielded same results whereas using 2) the runtime of `marg` was more than twice as slow. I't seems to me that for all three methods, the same compiler, `g++ = -std=gnu11`, was used.

I have no clue why this is happening; any suggestions?

Comment: Which operating system? Any other compiler options? Precompiled packages from CRAN (and source packages installed by `install.packages`) are compiled with the `-O2` option by default. It’s possible that `devtools::install` doesn’t do that (though it would be slightly surprising).

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. I've specified `CXX_STD = CXX11` in the `Makevars` file which is just standard in `RcppArmadillo`. I've just confirmed that `devtools` indeed uses `-02`.

Comment: OK I've just noticed that method 1) and 3) uses the `ccache g++-10` which I have long forgotten that I specified in `.R/Makevars`. But should this make a big difference? And would this imply, that others might not experience as good a performance without setting up `ccache`? I'm quite new to these settings.

Comment: `ccache` speeds up the *build time*, it does not make the compiled binaries faster. Hwoever, if you’re using a different (and newer!) compiler, this might occasionally make a difference, since different compiler versions apply different performance optimisations. That said, all three methods should be using the same compiler, since that is also specified via `Makevars` somewhere. If they use different compilers, something’s messed up in the configuration.

Comment: Yes, that was also my understanding of `ccache`. I'll live with the uncertainty. Thanks for the pointers!